# Kinect detect handpointer hover on tilebutton

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect

I'm trying to detect hovering (like onmouseover) on a tilebutton, but it has to be the build in hand pointer. I cannot find a build in event and I've tried this but it gives me an exception ( The invocation of the constructor on type 'Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls.KinectUserViewer' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception'

XAML giving the exception:

```
 <k:KinectUserViewer k:KinectRegion.KinectRegion="{Binding ElementName=kinectRegion}"     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"     Canvas.Left="820"/>
        <k:KinectRegion KinectSensor="{Binding Kinect, ElementName=kinectSensorChooser1}"     Height="919" Width="1920" x:Name="kinectRegion" Canvas.Top="151">
```

The buttons are automatically created by a forloop.

CS:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent HandPointerEnterEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "HandPointerEnter", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(EventHandler<HandPointerEventArgs>), typeof(KinectRegion));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent HandPointerLeaveEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "HandPointerLeave", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(EventHandler<HandPointerEventArgs>), typeof(KinectRegion));

...

 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KinectRegion.AddHandPointerEnterHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerEnter);
        KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLeaveHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerLeave);
 ....
 private void OnHandPointerEnter(object sender, HandPointerEventArgs handPointerEventArgs)
    {
        this.Close();//Trying to see if it works
    }
    private void OnHandPointerLeave(object sender, HandPointerEventArgs handPointerEventArgs)
    {
        this.Close();//Trying to see if it works
    }
```

What I've tried comes from this link:
[Hand over button event in Kinect SDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840187/hand-over-button-event-in-kinect-sdk-1-7)

However, if I remove the first two lines (public static), the program works but the hover isnt detected. With those lines it'll throw an exception.

Basically what I'm trying first is to detect the hover and then close the program (gives me a good idea if it works or not).

Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, I'm now trying to use `ButtonBase.Click` and `ButtonBase.MouseEnter` This works, apart from the MouseEnter, MouseEnter needs to be replaced by the handpointer...

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution, which works for it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your edition

```
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerEnterHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerEnter);
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLeaveHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerLeave);
```

first parameter 'this' means a Form

but it needs to be a "KinectTileButton"

My edition - it works.

```
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerEnterHandler(this.KinectTileButtonName, this.OnHandPointerEnter);
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLeaveHandler(this.KinectTileButtonName, this.OnHandPointerLeave);
```