# Kinect tile button hand hover

Tags: button, hover, kinect, tile

i'm starting to code in wpf/c# + sdk1.7

i just can't add a hover event for the hand cursor, this is my button:

```
<k:KinectTileButton x:Name="btn3" Canvas.Left="516" Canvas.Top="293" Click="btn3Click"  MouseMove="btn3MouseMove" MouseLeave="btn3MouseLeave" Height="520" Width="524" >
```

i guess it can't be so hard to do, i mean it's really basic if you pretend to use the hand as a cursor. why it doesn't exist? like MouseMove event.

i've tried with answers given here and still nothing. please help, keep in mind im really new into this!, thanks in advance.

[Hand over button event in Kinect SDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840187/hand-over-button-event-in-kinect-sdk-1-7)
[Kinect SDK 1.7 | Change KinectCursor image and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349748/kinect-sdk-1-7-change-kinectcursor-image-and-size)
[Kinect detect handpointer hover on tilebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563484/kinect-detect-handpointer-hover-on-tilebutton)

Answer (score -1):

Check the kinect SDK Samples. There is a button named `KinectHoverButton`. When you Hover it, it triggers the `click event` of the button.

```
<local:KinectHoverButton Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource KinectHoverButtonScrollLeftStyle}" Click="PageLeftButtonClick" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlsBasicsWindow, Path=PageLeftEnabled}"/>
```