# Kinect SDK 1.7 | Change KinectCursor image and size

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect-sdk

I have downloaded `Kinect SDK 1.7`, toolkit and have played with following samples.

- ControlBasics WPF
- InteractionGallery WPF.

I figured out that Kinect Toolkit internally uses the interaction frame to detect the hand position/gesture and accordingly maps it with the Kinect Controls.

I have a requirement where I want to capture a grip event on a Kinect Tile Button. Since the default KinectTileButton does not provide a Grip event. I added a grip event handler on my button.

```
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGripHandler(kinectButton, OnHandPointerCaptured);

private void OnHandPointerCaptured(object sender, HandPointerEventArgs handPointerEventArgs) 
{ 
    // Add code here
}
```

I placed a debug breakpoint inside the OnHandPointerCaptured  method and was able to receive proper hits when I grip on the KinectTileButton. But for some reason I do not see the KinectCursor image change to a grip as it happens on the KinectScrollViewer control.
I tried setting up the isGripTarget property in the KinectButtonBase class but it doesn't help.

```
private void InitializeKinectButtonBase() 
{ 
    KinectRegion.AddHandPointerPressHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerPress); 
    KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGotCaptureHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerCaptured); 
    KinectRegion.AddHandPointerPressReleaseHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerPressRelease); 
    KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLostCaptureHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerLostCapture); 
    KinectRegion.AddHandPointerEnterHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerEnter); 
    KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLeaveHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerLeave); 

    // Use the same OnHandPointerPress handler for the grip event 
    KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGripHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerPress); 

    //Set Kinect button as Grip target
    // KinectRegion.SetIsPressTarget(this, true); 
    KinectRegion.SetIsGripTarget(this, true);                
}
```

How do I change the KinectCursor image from openhand icon to grip, and also the size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what i found-

**1) Cursor Image and Size** - Both these samples use Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls project that defines the Custom Controls (KinectTileButton,KinectScrollViwer,KinectRegion etc.) used in these samples. The Kinect Cursor image and size is defined as a resource in 
Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls ->Themes->Generic.xaml. Search for following in the file -

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:KinectCursor}">
```

You can modify this as per your need. Wasn't able to find any properties/hooks exposed to control this directly from the UI.

**2) Grip event on Tile Button** - Kinect Button Supports various events which can be subsribed to and acted upon on your desire. see this 
[Hand over button event in Kinect SDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840187/hand-over-button-event-in-kinect-sdk-1-7?rq=1)

**3) Change Cursor image to Grip on Tile Button** - 
Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls project uses KinectCursorVisualizer.cs and KinectCursor.cs to render the virtual hand cursor on the UI. The Open Hand/Grip visual state is controlled via this Dependency Property defined in KinectCursor.cs.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsOpen",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(KinectCursor),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(true, (o, args) => ((KinectCursor)o).EnsureVisualState()));
```

A quick find all references on the property IsOpen tells that the only place where this property is set is in KinectCursorVisualizer.cs-> OnHandPointersUpdated method. Line- 229

```
// Set open state
 cursor.IsOpen = !pointer.IsInGripInteraction;
```

And this pointer.IsInGripInteraction property is set at KinectAdapter.cs Line 678

```
  handPointer.IsInGripInteraction = newIsInGripInteraction;
```

If you look at the code just above this line you'll find that this property is only set to true if the target element has a QueryInteractionStatusHandler defined and it sets
args.Handled , args.IsInGripInteraction property to true.

Since KinectScrollViewer has this handler defined you see a grip image.

```
 private void InitializeKinectScrollViewer()
        {
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGotCaptureHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerCaptured);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLostCaptureHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerLostCapture);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerEnterHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerEnter);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerMoveHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerMove);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerPressHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerPress);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGripHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerGrip);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGripReleaseHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerGripRelease);
//This is the QueryInteractionStatusHandler
            KinectRegion.AddQueryInteractionStatusHandler(this, this.OnQueryInteractionStatus);
            KinectRegion.SetIsGripTarget(this, true);
            this.scrollMoveTimer.Tick += this.OnScrollMoveTimerTick;
            this.scrollViewerInertiaScroller.SlowEnoughForSelectionChanged += this.OnSlowEnoughForSelectionChanged;

            // Create KinectRegion binding
            this.kinectRegionBinder = new KinectRegionBinder(this);
            this.kinectRegionBinder.OnKinectRegionChanged += this.OnKinectRegionChanged;    
        }
```

but KinectTileButton (extends KinectButtonBase) does not have this handler defined

```
 private void InitializeKinectButtonBase()
        {
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerPressHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerPress);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGotCaptureHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerCaptured);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerPressReleaseHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerPressRelease);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLostCaptureHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerLostCapture);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerEnterHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerEnter);
            KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLeaveHandler(this, this.OnHandPointerLeave);

            KinectRegion.SetIsPressTarget(this, true);

        }
```

How to define this handler ? - Simple add following to your UI. Can be added to constructor

```
//Add the handler
 KinectRegion.AddQueryInteractionStatusHandler(kinectButton, OnQuery);
```

Define the Handler

```
 //Variable to track GripInterationStatus
 bool isGripinInteraction = false;

        private void OnQuery(object sender, QueryInteractionStatusEventArgs handPointerEventArgs)
        {

            //If a grip detected change the cursor image to grip
            if (handPointerEventArgs.HandPointer.HandEventType == HandEventType.Grip)
            {
                isGripinInteraction = true;
                handPointerEventArgs.IsInGripInteraction = true;
            }

           //If Grip Release detected change the cursor image to open
            else if (handPointerEventArgs.HandPointer.HandEventType == HandEventType.GripRelease)
            {
                isGripinInteraction = false;
                handPointerEventArgs.IsInGripInteraction = false;
            }

            //If no change in state do not change the cursor
            else if (handPointerEventArgs.HandPointer.HandEventType == HandEventType.None)
            {
                handPointerEventArgs.IsInGripInteraction = isGripinInteraction;
            }

            handPointerEventArgs.Handled = true;
        }
```

You may have to tweak this as per your requirement. **Happy Kinecting :)**

Comment: Can I just say thank you so friggin much for this. You have saved me hours of time and possibly my sanity. I got as far as working out I needed KinectRegion.SetIsGripTarget() but couldn't work out the next step. Thank you again, works perfectly; I wish I could upvote 1000 times...

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Thanks for the nice words :)